# Find user who approved comments in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

On Wordpress 3.4, is there any functionality or any way using which I can find who (which user) approved some particular comments?

I have a blog that is having a multiple admin and few comments that are spam but not approved by anyone. I think its hacking or a compromise of someone password... so need to figure out as which user account is used to approve the comment?

I have tried to find out, but unable to find any way to find this information? May be someone here has an idea on how to get this information from wordpress.

Comment: There's now way it could be a user with a previously approved genuine comment?  Is 'Comment author must have a previously approved comment' checked in Settings->Discussion?

Comment: I have checked this... it is already disabled.